# Disable nginx caching for images in particular directory

Tags: nginx, cache

There is a directory on my webserver which contains images that I don't want to be cached.

Nginx is frontend to Apache. I have caching enabled for static resources in nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
        server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;

        location / {
            root /home/somedomain/public_html/site;
            proxy_pass  http://backend;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
        }

        location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
                  root /home/somedomain/public_html/site;
                  add_header  Last-Modified: $date_gmt;
                  expires 1y;
                  access_log off;
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|bmp|swf)$ {
                  root /home/somedomain/public_html/site;
                  expires max;
                  access_log off;
        }

        location ~ \.php { 
            proxy_pass  http://backend;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
        }


}
```

I tried to add to the end:

```
location /home/somedomain/public_html/site/dontcache/ \.png {
                 root /home/somedomain/public_html/site/dontcache;
                 expires off;
}
```

Also tried `expires -1;` and `expires 1m;` but all of that doesnt seem to work.

I know it is simple but I just can't get why it doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
location ^~ /home/somedomain/public_html/site/dontcache/ {
  root /home/somedomain/public_html/site/dontcache;
  expires epoch;
}
```

The order of matching for `location` directives is described [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location)

Comment: On wordpress websites, can I enable this for wp-admin areas?

`location ^~ /wordpress/wp-admin {
      expires epoch;
      proxy_no_cache 1; 
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
location /home/somedomain/public_html/site/dontcache/ \.png {
                 root /home/somedomain/public_html/site/dontcache;
                 proxy_no_cache 1;
}
```

Also, look here: http://sysoev.ru/nginx/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_no_cache

Comment: Wrong answer. The original configuration does not use `proxy_cache` at all.

Comment: My bad. I was messed by "I have caching enabled for static resources in nginx.conf:"